# Partition pruning on Spark delta lake merge

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

I'm using delta lake ("io.delta" %% "delta-core" % "0.4.0") and merge in foreachBatch like:

```
foreachBatch { (s, batchid) =>
        deltaTable.alias("t")
          .merge(
            s.as("s"),
            "s.eventid = t.eventid and t.categories in ('a1', 'a2')")
          .whenMatched("s.eventtime < t.eventtime").updateAll()
          .whenNotMatched().insertAll()
          .execute()
      }
```

The delta table is partitioned on categories. If I add partition filter like 'and t.categories in ('a1', 'a2')', from spark graph I can see the input is not the whole table. I think it did partition pruning. However, if I do:
"s.eventid = t.eventid and t.categories=s.categories", it still loads all the data from delta table. I expect it can automatically sense which partitions it should go to do the join, kind of pushdown. Is that possible to have the partition pruning without specifying the specific partition values? I also tried to add ("spark.databricks.optimizer.dynamicPartitionPruning","true") but not work.

Thanks

Comment: Same issue i am facing in version 0.5 as well.

Comment: dynamic partiiton pruning only available with databricks runtime 5.5 lts

Answer (score 3):

You could pass that in two ways. One is static way of passing the values and other is you do dynamically set the partitions in the merge statement.

1. Static way of passing the partition values.

```
val categoriesList = List("a1", "a2")  
val catergoryPartitionList  = categoriesList.mkString("','")

foreachBatch { (s, batchid) =>
    deltaTable.alias("t")
      .merge(
        s.as("s"),
        "s.eventid = t.eventid and t.categories in ('$catergoryPartitionList')")
      .whenMatched("s.eventtime < t.eventtime").updateAll()
      .whenNotMatched().insertAll()
      .execute()
  }
```

2. The dynamic way of passing the categories to Merge statement is as under :

```
val selectedCategories = deltaTable.select("categories").dropDuplicates()
  
val categoriesList = selectedCategories.map(_.getString(0)).collect()

val catergoryPartitionList  = categoriesList.mkString("','")

foreachBatch { (s, batchid) =>
    deltaTable.alias("t")
      .merge(
        s.as("s"),
        "s.eventid = t.eventid and t.categories in ('$catergoryPartitionList')")
      .whenMatched("s.eventtime < t.eventtime").updateAll()
      .whenNotMatched().insertAll()
      .execute()
  }
```

Comment: I am not getting the dynamic part :)

Comment: Dynamic part in the sense you are processing some table that has multiple categories value and your table is partitioned by category and during particular run do have some random categories then that might handle it without hardcoding values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I tried this stuff in production using open source delta 1.0 but I did not see the partition pruning happening. Could you happen to know which version was the partition pruning added

Comment: There are no details but which faetures where released in 1.0 and we have documentation from 2.0. You can find those on github here : https://github.com/delta-io/delta/releases/ but Iam also not aware about the version.

Comment: Actually the partition pruning worked correctly in 1.0 ! I had a bug in my code. Hope it helps